# DataGrip: Как изменить значение оператора LIMIT в стандартном запросе при клике на таблицу?

Tags: sql, datagrip

В DataGrip, как изменить значение оператора `LIMIT` в стандартном запросе при клике на таблицу, в дереве схем/таблиц? По умолчанию `LIMIT 501`, поменять к примеру на `LIMIT 10`

```
SELECT t.*
FROM you_schema.you_table t
LIMIT 501
```

Comment: Посмотри, это должно помочь: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207287649-Limit-the-number-of-rows-when-previewing-a-table-in-DataGrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это значение можно изменить здесь: "Preferences" -> "Database" -> "Data Views" -> **Limit page size to**
Для версии DataGrip 2020.2.2 - актуально